# Декодирование URL

Tags: c#, decode

Нужно декодировать URL

Поискав заранее ответы на свой вопрос - нашёл вот это:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847593/8852899

Но все эти три метода декодируют, но как бы не полностью.

- Поэтому боюсь что то потерять.

Вот такие штуки у меня в одном месте остаются:

```
&#x427;&#x442;&#x43E; &#x438;&#x441;
```

В тоже время, вот этот сайт в той же строке - ничего такого не оставляет

https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Как добиться такого же результата ?

Что в тех методах не так ?

**PS.** Сайт не реклама - удалю как только разберусь.

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного ошибаетесь. У вас не URL, а HTML.

- Ваш текст: `Что ис`.
- URL вид: `%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81`
- HTML вид: `&#x427;&#x442;&#x43E; &#x438;&#x441;` или `&#1063;&#1090;&#1086; &#1080;&#1089;`

Как видите они совершенно отличаются. По этой причине методы, как `HttpUtility.UrlDecode();` у вас и не сработали. Решение простое, используйте например `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode();`.

Comment: Остаются -  имел ввиду такими становятся: &#x427;&#x442;&#x43E; &#x438;&#x441; примерно из такого %D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81
Возможно мне нужно 2мя методоми пройтись - попробую) спасибо!